# Blank page with LAMP

Tags: php, apache

Well, this question has been asked for years, but I still can't get it working.

I want to access to my yourls application --> http://app.sevendats.com/yourls/admin/
As you can see, it won't work; blank page. How can I display the error? Or see it in the php_error.log?

The configs are too long, so I'll link them:

phpinfo() --> http://sevendats.com/phpinfo.php

php.ini --> http://sevendats.com/php.ini

httpd.conf --> http://sevendats.com/httpd.conf

My /var/log/php_errors.log has chmod 777 and chown apache:apache

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://github.com/claudehohl/Stikked/issues/112.

Comment: You should include the text in the post rather than posting links because your question is not useful once your change the content of the links (or delete the links altogether).

Comment: @kkuilla I can't, stackoverflow says that the body is limited to 30.000 characters :(

Comment: @SujitAgarwal That's not my error...

Comment: You should read how to create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting. You will have a much higher chance of getting a useful answer if you follow the instructions.

Comment: Your question is too broad too be honest.

Answer (score 0):

In the index.php file of your yourls-app set this right after the opening php tag

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```